# x86_64 Inline Assembly ; Copying 64-bit register directly to 64-bit memory location

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am running the code below and suffering from two problems:

1) The moment I change movl (to copy values from registers) to movq I face the gcc error : `Error: operand size mismatch for movq`. In the normal assembly I see that this was possible by adding qword prefix or likes, but that also fails to satisfy gcc

```
uint64_t cpuid_0(uint64_t* _rax, uint64_t* _rbx, uint64_t* _rcx, uint64_t* _rdx){

    int a, b, c, d;
    *_rax = 0x0;

    __asm__
    __volatile__
    (
        "movq $0,  %%rax\n"
        "cpuid\n"
        "movl %%eax, %0\n"
        "movl %%ebx, %1\n"
        "movl %%ecx, %2\n"
        "movl %%edx, %3\n"
        : "=r" (a), "=r" (b), "=r" (c), "=r" (d)
        : "0" (a)
    );
    *_rax=a;*_rbx=b;*_rcx=c;*_rdx=d;
    return *_rax;
}
```

2) I want to eliminate extra copy operation so I modified my code in the constraint specification:

```
uint64_t cpuid_0(uint64_t* _rax, uint64_t* _rbx, uint64_t* _rcx, uint64_t* _rdx){

    int a, b, c, d;
    *_rax = 0x0;

    __asm__
    __volatile__
    (
         "movq $0,  %%rax\n"
         "cpuid\n"
         "movl %%eax, %0\n"
         "movl %%ebx, %1\n"
         "movl %%ecx, %2\n"
         "movl %%edx, %3\n"
        : "+m" (*_rax), "=m" (*_rbx), "=m" (*_rcx), "=m" (_rdx)
        : "0" (*_rax)
    );
    *_rax=a;*_rbx=b;*_rcx=c;*_rdx=d;
    return *_rax;
}
```

This gives me a host of errors like those below:

```
warning: matching constraint does not allow a register
error: inconsistent operand constraints in an ‘asm’
```

Also, I assume `__volatile__` could be removed in this small code.

Comment: When you changed `movl` to `movq`, did you change `eax` to `rax` too? (And similarly for the other registers)?

Comment: Also, why use `mov` at all? Why not just let the constraints do the work for you?

Comment: Yes, I did that and still gcc was complaining of  constraint errors and I am sorry, I am new to inline assembly. Thanks in advance, if you show me the way. Also, please let me know how do I use memory constraints correctly. As I do not want to perform extra copy.

Comment: Doesn't gcc have a `cpuid.h`?  Why write this yourself if gcc has already made one for you?  Presumably they know how to do it best.

Comment: Honestly, I knew that, but have never used inline assembly. Discount me as student? Not from any university though.

Comment: @ultimatecause Did you also change the size of `_rax` and friends to be 64 bit types when you changed `movl` to `movq` and `eax` to `rax`?

Comment: And lastly: What is the question you want to have answered?

Comment: Yes, I changed both movl->movq and eax -> rax. Isn't _rax already a 64 bit type? I am on 64-bit Linux, hosted on Xen hypervisor.

Comment: I would like to understand my mistakes in both the problems.

Comment: @ultimatecause `int` is a 32 bit type on most 64 bit systems, including Linux.  Using `long long` or `int64_t` to get a 64 bit type for sure.   The problem in your second variant (with `m` constraints) is that matching a constraing with the `0` constraint is only possible if that constraint refers to a register.  And I don't think you need that here anyway.

Comment: When debugging assembler errors from inline asm, it often helps to look at how GCC filled in the `%0` and so on substitutions in the template.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/3vj8tM.  That's the raw asm output from GCC, *before* it tries to feed that to the assembler.  (From the first one, which only fails at assemble time, not compile time.  Those are separate, gcc doesn't understand asm.)  `%eax` is a 32-bit register so `movq %eax, %rdi` won't work.

Comment: BTW, if your inline asm template starts or ends with `mov`, you're almost always doing it inefficiently.  Use constraints like `"+a"(a)` and `"=b"(b)` and let the compiler decide how to get data in / out of the registers that CPUID reads and writes.  (Note that ECX is also a possible input for some EAX values.)  Also, if you want different sizes of the same register operand, you can do stuff like `%k0` in the template to expand to the 32-bit version or `%q0` to print the name of the 64-bit full register.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I am getting it - Please let me know how can I handle pointers in the constraints.

Comment: `"=b" (*ptr)`.  The C object pointed to by `ptr` gets the value that's in BX/EBX/RBX at the end of the asm statement.  The compiler can make that happen by emitting a `mov` store, or by optimizing away the pointer variable when inlining this wrapper function into the caller.  e.g. if you called this function and then used the output values right away as args to `printf`, the compiler might just emit `mov %ebx, %esi`.  This is why we have optimizing compilers in the first place, instead of writing everything by hand in assembly language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the input `"0" (*_rax)` which is foxing it... it seems that `"0"` does not work with a `"=m"` memory constraint, nor with `"+m"`.  (I do not know why.)

Changing your second function to compile and work:

```
uint32_t cpuid_0(uint32_t* _eax, uint32_t* _ebx, uint32_t* _ecx, uint32_t* _edx)
{
  __asm__
  (
    "mov $0,  %%eax\n"
    "cpuid\n"
    "mov %%eax, %0\n"
    "mov %%ebx, %1\n"
    "mov %%ecx, %2\n"
    "mov %%edx, %3\n"
    : "=m" (*_eax), "=m" (*_ebx), "=m" (*_ecx), "=m" (*_edx)
    : //"0" (*_eax) -- not required and throws errors !!
    : "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"  // ESSENTIAL "clobbers"
  ) ;
  return *_eax ;
}
```

where that:

- does everything as uint32_t, for consistency.
- discards the redundant `int a, b, c, d;`
- omits the `"0"` input, which in any case was not being used.
- declares simple "=m" output for `(*_eax)`
- "clobbers" all "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
- discards the redundant **volatile**.

The last is **essential**, because without it the compiler has no idea that those registers are affected.

The above compiles to:

```
   push   %rbx                 # compiler (now) knows %rbx is "clobbered"
   mov    %rdx,%r8             # likewise %rdx
   mov    %rcx,%r9             # ditto %rcx

     mov    $0x0,%eax          # the __asm__(....
     cpuid  
     mov    %eax,(%rdi)
     mov    %ebx,(%rsi)
     mov    %ecx,(%r8)
     mov    %edx,(%r9)         # ....) ;

   mov    (%rdi),%eax
   pop    %rbx
   retq
```

NB: without the "clobbers" compiles to:

```
   mov    $0x0,%eax
   cpuid  
   mov    %eax,(%rdi)
   mov    %ebx,(%rsi)
   mov    %ecx,(%rdx)
   mov    %edx,(%rcx)
   mov    (%rdi),%eax
   retq
```

which is shorter, but sadly doesn't work !!

---

You could also (version 2):

```
struct cpuid
{
  uint32_t  eax ;
  uint32_t  ebx ;
  uint32_t  ecx ;
  uint32_t  edx ;
};

uint32_t cpuid_0(struct cpuid* cid)
{
  uint32_t eax ;

  __asm__
  (
    "mov $0,  %%eax\n"
    "cpuid\n"
    "mov %%ebx, %1\n"
    "mov %%ecx, %2\n"
    "mov %%edx, %3\n"
    : "=a" (eax), "=m" (cid->ebx), "=m" (cid->ecx), "=m" (cid->edx)
    :: "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx"
  ) ;

  return cid->eax = eax ;
}
```

which compiles to something very slightly shorter:

```
   push   %rbx
   mov    $0x0,%eax
   cpuid  
   mov    %ebx,0x4(%rdi)
   mov    %ecx,0x8(%rdi)
   mov    %edx,0xc(%rdi)
   pop    %rbx
   mov    %eax,(%rdi)
   retq
```

---

Or you could do something more like your first version (version 3):

```
uint32_t cpuid_0(struct cpuid* cid)
{
  uint32_t eax, ebx, ecx, edx ;

  eax = 0 ;
  __asm__(" cpuid\n" : "+a" (eax), "=b" (ebx), "=c" (ecx), "=d" (edx));

  cid->edx = edx ;
  cid->ecx = ecx ;
  cid->ebx = ebx ;
  return cid->eax = eax ;
}
```

which compiles to:

```
   push   %rbx
   xor    %eax,%eax
   cpuid  
   mov    %ebx,0x4(%rdi)
   mov    %edx,0xc(%rdi)
   pop    %rbx
   mov    %ecx,0x8(%rdi)
   mov    %eax,(%rdi)
   retq
```

This version uses the `"+a"`, `"=b"` etc. magic to tell the compiler to allocate specific registers to the various variables.  This reduces the amount of assembler to the bare minimum, which is generally a Good Thing.  [Note that the compiler knows that `xor %eax,%eax` is better (and shorter) than `mov $0,%eax` and thinks there is some advantage to doing the `pop %rbx` earlier.]

---

Better yet -- following comment by @Peter Cordes (version 4):

```
uint32_t cpuid_1(struct cpuid* cid)
{
  __asm__
  (
    "xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
    "cpuid\n"
    : "=a" (cid->eax), "=b" (cid->ebx), "=c" (cid->ecx), "=d" (cid->edx)
  ) ;

  return cid->eax ;
}
```

where the compiler figures out that `cid->eax` is already in `%eax`, and so compiles to:

```
   push   %rbx
   xor    %eax,%eax
   cpuid  
   mov    %ebx,0x4(%rdi)
   mov    %eax,(%rdi)
   pop    %rbx
   mov    %ecx,0x8(%rdi)
   mov    %edx,0xc(%rdi)
   retq
```

which is the same as version 3, apart from a small difference in the order of the instructions.

---

FWIW: an `__asm__()` is defined to be:

`asm` *asm-qualifiers* `(`*AssemblerTemplate* `:` *OutputOperands [* `:` *InputOperands [* `:` *Clobbers ] ]* `)`

The key to inline assembler is to understand that the compiler:

- has *no idea* what the *AssemblerTemplate* part means.

  It does expand the `%xx` place holders, but understands *nothing* else.
- *does* understand the *OutputOperands*, *InputOperands* (if any) and *Clobbers* (if any)...

  ...these tell the compiler what the assembler needs as parameters, and how to expand the various `%xx`.

  ...but these **also** tell the compiler what the *AssemblerTemplate* **does**, in terms that the compiler understands.

So, what the compiler understands is a sort of "data flow".  It understands that the assembler takes a number of inputs, returns a number of outputs and (may) as a side effect "clobber" some registers and/or amounts of memory.  Armed with this information, the compiler can integrate the "black box" assembler sequence with the code generated around it.  Among other things the compiler will:

- allocate registers for output and input operands

  and arrange for the inputs to be in the required registers (as required).

  NB: the compiler looks on the assembler as a single operation, where all inputs are consumed before any outputs are generated.  If an input is not used after the `__asm__()` the compiler can allocate a given register as an input and as an output.  Hence the need so the so-called "early clobber".
- move the "black box" around wrt the surrounding code, maintaining the dependencies the assembler has on the sources of its inputs and the dependencies the code that follows has on the assembler's outputs.
- discard the "black box" altogether if nothing seems to depend on its outputs !

Comment: You can use `"=b" (cid->ebx)`; no need to use a named temporary variable to capture the register output. Any lvalue works.  Also, one of your earlier versions special cased `"=a" (eax)` while the others used `"=m" (cid->ebx)` for some reason (instead of letting the asm be less bad by using `"=rm"`).  No reason for that; there was no input from C in the EAX register, just a hard-coded `mov`-immediate instruction inside the template.  For output purposes, EAX isn't special.  Same would be the case if you used a separate `"a"(level)` input operand.

Comment: I think we can do one step better still: get rid of our `xor` instruction and do `"a"(0)` as an input constraint instead. This saves an instruction when GCC can prove it's already zero, such as if it gets inlined into code like `if(!f()) cpuid_1(&cid);`.